# How can I recenter grep or compile window on next error

Tags: compilation-mode, grep

On `next-error` in the grep or compilation window, I can use something like

```
(setq next-error-recenter 35)
```

to ensure that window displaying the match scrolls to show the whole match, as described in more detail in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796929/cursor-position-in-the-buffer-after-next-error/22798416#22798416).

How do I do the same thing in the grep or compilation window itself? I often have grep output or compile output that is off the bottom of the window, and on days when I spend all of my time going through grep output or compile errors, switching back and forth between windows adds a significant overhead.

Comment: You want to look at `compilation-goto-locus` and put in a `recenter` command where appropriate -- at the section that begins with the comment:  `If the compilation buffer window was selected . . . ,`  You can recenter at different location of the window -- see the doc-string for `recenter`.

Comment: Added a command `recenter-current-error`, bound to `l` in the
`*Occur*` and `*Grep*` buffers; the effect of this command is like
calling `C-l` in the window displaying the current error.  This will
be available in a future release Emacs-28.

Answer (score 1):

I use such workaround for the exact saving of `point` position in the `compilation/grep` buffer:

```el
(defun eab/compile-goto-error ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((istc? truncate-lines))
    (toggle-truncate-lines t)
    (let ((buf (current-buffer))
          (line (- (count-lines (window-start) (point))
                   (if (eq (point) (point-at-bol)) 0 1)))
          (point (point)))
      (compile-goto-error)
      (run-with-timer 0.01 nil `(lambda ()
                                 (let ((cb (current-buffer)))
                                       (pop-to-buffer ,buf)
                                       (recenter ,line)
                                       (goto-char ,point)
                                       (toggle-truncate-lines ,istc?)
                                       (pop-to-buffer cb)))))))
```

If you want simple centering of the `point` in the `compilation/grep` buffer, use:

```el
(defun eab/next-error ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
    (next-error)
    (run-with-timer 0.01 nil `(lambda ()
                             (let ((cb (current-buffer)))
                               (pop-to-buffer ,buf)
                               (recenter)
                               (pop-to-buffer cb))))))
```

You can use `next-error` instead of `compile-goto-error` in the first example.

Upd. Emacs 25.1 is needed for non-zero time period.